# What species is this white thin shell? Santa Cruz, California

Tags: species-identification, marine-biology

These shells (see in green circle) are empty inside which look like very flat marble donuts/coins.
The small ones are like dollar coins; big ones can be cup coaster-sized.

It has beautiful five-fold symmetry (see the top one) on its back and a whole on its ventral part. Must be related to sea urchin?

What's more interesting is that some of them (see the one at the bottom) have a tiny shell of a different kind anchored on them.

[image]
[image]

Comment: In your second photograph, are you referring to the white conical shell or the little black thing?

Comment: sorry for not being clear. Trying to refer to the same thing - flat white shells

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are definitely sea urchins, specifically a type of sand dollar called the [Eccentric Sand Dollar](https://www.americanoceans.org/species/eccentric-sand-dollar/), which is found all along the Pacific coast of of the US. Here's what they look like when they're alive:

[image]

They're filter feeders partially buried in the sand.

If you're referring to the white, conical shell attached to the sand dollar, that's a barnacle, probably a California Barnacle, but the species is easier to identify alive (or newly dead) than bleached and eroded (to me, anyway.)

Comment: you are amazing!

Comment: @Code42 - Thanks, but I just happen to like sand dollars and I'm good at searches. :)